# show uiactivityview while an other operation is loading

Tags: iphone, ios4, selector, uiactivityindicatorview

i googled for hours now but i can't find a code example, which describes how to show an uiactivityview while an operation/method is loading.

in my case i want to show it while i load a large image to an uiimageview. have you got an idea how to realize that?

thanks in advance.
sean

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look in the [UI UIActivityIndicatorView Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIActivityIndicatorView_Class/Reference/UIActivityIndicatorView.html) documentation.

Make sure to return to the run loop while waiting for the image to load in order to see the activity indicator animating.  Also, you will probably need to create a method to stop the activity indicator, and perhaps call that stop method by doing a performSelectorOnMainThread from whatever method handles the asynchronous completion of the loading.

Answer (score 0):

well its quit easy.

1. show activity indicator
2. start thread loading that image
3. if image loaded, thread tells mainapp to kill activity indicator.

---

```
   NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(myMethod)
```

toTarget:self 
  withObject:nil];

and

```
      [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(myMethod) 
           withObject:nil 
           waitUntilDone:false];
```

will be helpfully.
taken from http://www.iphoneexamples.com/